# Problema al hacer UPDATE a datos en MySql a traves de PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Buenas noches**

Estoy intentando realizar una actualización a una de mis tablas de mi base de datos.
Para identificar la fila que voy a actualizar uso como mi base para la búsqueda un correo electrónico que ingreso en un formulario antes de solicitar que ingrese el resto de datos a actualiza.
El problema es que después de realizar la operación me arroja un error y no he sido capaz de encontrar mi falla.
En este sitio uso:

- Pagina en la que solicito los datos.
- Un PHP de conexión.
- Un PHP que procesa la actualización.
- La base de datos.

A continuación ilustrare el proceso y dispondré de fragmento de código, *agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.*

**Pantalla en la que solicito e ingreso los datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo del formulario**

```
<label>Localidad</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelLocalidad1" required/> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Direccion</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelDireccion1" required/> 
    </div>
   <div class="form-element">
        <label>Codigo Postal</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelPostal1" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Providencia</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelProvidencia1" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Numero de telefono</label>
        <input type="number" name="labeltelefono1" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>    
        
     <button type="submit" name="PAGO" value="PAGO">Registrar direccion</button>    
                            </form>
```

**Codigo de conexion**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$clave = "";
$bd  = "usuarios";
$conectar = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave,$bd);
?>
```

**Código del PHP que realiza la modificación**

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

 $idusuario= session_id();
 $localidad  = $_POST['labelLocalidad1'];
 $direccion  = $_POST['labelDireccion1'];
 $postal = $_POST['labelPostal1'];
 $providencia  = $_POST['labelProvidencia1'];
 $telefono  = $_POST['labeltelefono1'];
 $correoentrega  = $_POST['labelcorreo1'];
 

$actualizar =("UPDATE datosentrega set localidad='$localidad',direccion='$direccion',postal=$postal,providencia='$providencia',telefono='$telefono' WHERE correoentrega='$correoentrega'");                     
$query = mysqli_query($conectar,$actualizar);

if($query){

   echo "<script> alert('Datos registrados');
    
   </script>";

}else{
    echo "<script> alert('Error favor de revisar el codigo XD');
  
    </script>";
}
```

**Agradeceré de todo corazón cualquier ayuda, buenas noches y muchas gracias de antemano**

Comment: Es que no me manda ningún error

Comment: Solo se va a la opcion de Erorr favor de revisar el codigo de mi if else

Comment: No veo que hayas añadido al elemento con el nombre `labelcorreo1` en el formulario. Por otro lado, puedes obtener el código y mensaje de error producido en la ejecución de la consulta de la siguiente manera:

`$query = mysqli_query($conectar, $actualizar) or exit(mysqli_errno($conectar) . ': ' . mysqli_error($conectar));`

También tienes la opción de imprimir la consulta SQL como texto, copiarla y ejecutarla en el `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: ¡¡Usa mysqli_error() para conocer el error!! Y mucho cuidado, tu código permite injección de SQL. Investiga un poco sobre ello.